# Are variable/function names unique to the surrounding jQuery( function( $ )?

Tags: jquery, scope

With the code below would I need to worry about other scripts (external or inline) overriding my function and variables? Or as this is within the `jQuery( function( $ ) {` function is `myfunction` and `myVariable` unique to that block of code?

```
<script>

    jQuery( function( $ ) {

        function myfunction() {

            console.log( 'test1' );

        }

        myfunction();

        var myVariable = 'test2';

    });

</script>
```

Comment: jQuery( function( $ ) { creates a closure making the function and variable inside inaccessible outside that closure and if duplicates exist at higher level the ones inside closure will shadow them